# Copy Connector while creating an instance of an element in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I tried to create an instance of a DataObject with the option 'Copy Connectors' checked. I expect EA to copy all my connections from the 'main' DataObject but EA creates an instance which is not connected to any element. 
any idea what I'm probably doing wrong?
I#m using EA version 12.0.1207

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, EAUI...

You need to drag/drop more than one element. That means you have multiple elements selected. Here you select the connected `Class1` and `Class2`:

[image]

This results in:

[image]

If they have connectors, the instances will also be connected. Doing it one by one will not create connectors on the instances.

Comment: So I have a diagram with a DataObject connected to an activity. I create an instance of the DataObject in the same diagram with 'Copy Connectors' checked in. I expect that the instance created will be connected to the activity too since its a connection + if I use "Insert related elements" then I should be able to see my connections from other diagrams. Currently I just get an instance without any connections.

Comment: Please read, what I wrote. More than one element "at the same time" is what I meant.

Comment: @NehaRamesh what he means is that you need to copy and paste as new all elements that have a relationship to keep the relationship, otherwise the relationship will not be kept

Comment: @NehaRamesh you can use the "TimeAware" functionality of version 13 to "Clone as a new version" an element, I think its closer to what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas and Mart10. I appreciate your time. I am able to make the connections when I'm dragging/copying the elements together. That's very helpful.
 Although it only creates the relationship between the dragged elements. 

I was hoping there was a way in which all the relationships of the classifier element can be seen/connected in the instance of the object.